# Unable to insert data in Hive for JSON file

Tags: hadoop, hive, create-table

Failed!!
Create the table for below schema

```
(schema = {"type":"record","name":"topLevelRecord","fields":[{"name":"MESSAGE_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"MSGNAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"SOURCE","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"EVENT_DATETIME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"CUSTOMER_ORDER_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"SP_ORGANISATION_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_TYPE_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_SUBTYPE_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_REASON_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_DATE","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_CHANNEL_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_RETAILER_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_DEALER_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_AFFILIATE_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_EMPLOYEE_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_CREATED_CONTACT_CENTRE_AGENT_ID","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_SUBMITTED_DATE","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_SUBMITTED_CHANNEL_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_DUE_DATE","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ONE_TIME_CHARGE_AMT","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"RECURRING_CHARGE_AMT","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_STATUS_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON_NAME","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"CREATE_JOB_RUN_ID","type":"int"},{"name":"CREATE_DATE_TIME","type":"string"},{"name":"SYSTEM_ID","type":"int"},{"name":"SRC_FILE_NAME","type":"string"}]}
```

I am new to hive just tried out by just looking around and came up with below Query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE governed_data.customer_order(
message_id string,
msgname string,
source string,
event_datetime string,
customer_order_id string,
sp_organisation_name string,
customer_account_id string,
order_type_name string,
order_subtype_name string,
order_reason_name string,
order_created_date string,
order_created_channel_name string,
order_created_retailer_id string,
order_created_dealer_id string,
order_created_affiliate_id string,
order_created_employee_id string,
order_created_contact_centre_agent_id string,
order_submitted_date string,
order_submitted_channel_name string,
order_due_date string,
one_time_charge_amt string,
recurring_charge_amt string,
order_status_name string,
order_status_change_reason_name string,
create_job_run_id int,
create_date_time string,
system_id int,
src_file_name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS AVRO
location 'adl://rbsitbinsighstdlt001.azuredatalakestore.net/insights/governed_data/';
```

In the i want to insert data in the hive Database

Answer (score 0):

You specified stored as `AVRO` and serde is `JsonSerde`, these properties are conflicting.

If you need AVRO, then specify the serde as `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe`, specify the `inputformat` as `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat`, and the `outputformat` as `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat`. Also provide a location from which the AvroSerde will pull the most current schema for the table.

See example here: [Creating Avro-backed Hive tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-CreatingAvro-backedHivetables)

Or simply specify `STORED AS AVRO`, without SerDe, Input and Output format. Try to remove `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'` in your DDL.

And if you want JsonSerDe to parse attributes then create table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE governed_data.customer_order(message_id string,
msgname string,
source string,
event_datetime string,
customer_order_id string,
sp_organisation_name string,
customer_account_id string,
order_type_name string,
order_subtype_name string,
order_reason_name string,
order_created_date string,
order_created_channel_name string,
order_created_retailer_id string,
order_created_dealer_id string,
order_created_affiliate_id string,
order_created_employee_id string,
order_created_contact_centre_agent_id string,
order_submitted_date string,
order_submitted_channel_name string,
order_due_date string,
one_time_charge_amt string,
recurring_charge_amt string,
order_status_name string,
order_status_change_reason_name string,
create_job_run_id int,
create_date_time string,
system_id int,
src_file_name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 'adl://rbsitbinsighstdlt001.azuredatalakestore.net/insights/governed_data/' 
;
```

Read also docs about [JsonSerDe](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

Comment: I tried just like u told me and got below error:                                  TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Not a data file.
     and so on..................

Comment: @smasherbk201 check table location. Does it contain data files?

Comment: Yes, There are data files in the location.